# Button Click Fails to Redirect to Intended URL

Tags: python, html, django, mqtt

I'm attempting to click on a button that should lead me to a specific page in my URLs  but  it's not functioning as expected.

mainpage.html:

```
<form method="POST">

<input type="button" name="Show Result" onclick="location.href='{% url 'get_result' %}'" 
value="Show Result"></input>
</form>
```

my pages in view :

```
def get_result(request):

    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
        client.subscribe("a",)
    
    result = None
    
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        global result
        result = msg.payload.decode("utf-8")
        print("Received message:", result)

    client = mqtt.Client("p1")
    client.connect("127.0.0.1", 1883)
    client.publish("test", 'C:/Users/HP/Desktop/reallifeviolencesituation/NV_4.mp4')
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message
    client.loop_forever()
    context = {'result': result}
    return render(request, "result.html", context)
```

my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', showvideo, name='showvideo'),
    path('get_result/', get_result, name='get_result')
   
]
```

thanks

Comment: `client.loop_forever()` will never return

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. `<input>` does not use a closing tag. Remove that.

Comment: Thanks! It works  but the 'result' variable is showing as 'none' instead of the expected result please can you post how to show the result @hardillb

Comment: What you are trying to do here is not really going to work. You are trying to map a synchronous protocol (HTTP) to an asynchronous protocol (MQTT). This is not something you can do without a very detailed understanding of the difference.

Answer (score 0):

First an explanation about why what you have won't work.

1. As mentioned in the comments, `client.loop_forever()` does just that, so would never return
2. You are leaking mqtt clients, every time the code it called it creates a new client
3. You have a fixes client id, so the clients will kick each other off the broker each time they try and connect, the more clients there are (see point 2) the worse it will get.
4. What happens if there is never a response (e.g. the client that processes the first message is down)
5. If multiple people have the page open at the same time then there is the possibility of a race condition between different clients pressing the button.

I suggest you do not try to involve the django backend in this at all, replace the HTTP request with an in page JavaScript MQTT client that can send the message and listen for the response and use that response to trigger a page navigation if needed. This is a lot simpler than trying to wrap HTTP round a MQTT request/response pattern.

You will need a broker that supports and has been configured for MQTT over WebSockets.